# trouble with .get() in tkinter, getting things from a list of entries

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I'm working on a python 2.7 sudoku checker and am having trouble with the `.get()`, as it seems it is only working on the last frame (bottom row of entries), the rest just stores empty strings. there's 8 lines marked as test that should output what is currently on the entries.
Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def armar(x):
        global sudoku
        global matriz
        for i in range(9):
                for j in range(9):
                        if matriz[i][j].get()!="":
                           sudoku[i][j]=matriz[i][j].get()
                           sudoku[i][j]=int(sudoku[i][j])
                        else:
                           sudoku[i][j]=0
        #test---------------------------------
        for fila in sudoku:
                for numero in fila:
                        print numero,
                print
        for fila in matriz:
                for numero in fila:
                        print numero.get(),
                print
        #---------------------------------------
matriz = [[0]*9]*9
sudoku = [[0]*9]*9
marco = [0]*9

#-------------Window---------------
ventana = Tk()

#Marcos
for i in range(9):
        marco[i]=Frame(ventana)
        marco[i].pack()

#Cuadricula
for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
                matriz[i][j]=Entry(marco[i], width=3)
                matriz[i][j].pack(side=LEFT)
                matriz[i][j].bind("<Return>", armar)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Setting up the matrix as `[[0] * 9] * 9` is *not* a good idea; change a value in one row, and you change the value in every row!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I did not know that. What is the correct way of setting it up?

Comment: `matrix = [[0 for _ in range(9)] for _ in range(9)]`